# CORS Filter not working in my java application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, cors, servlet-filters

I am using jdk 8 and added tomcat-catalina in my build.gradle and configured the following values in web.xml but it doesn't return response headers when the request URL accessed.

build.gradle:

`compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.29'`

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It doesn't work for me..

**Resonse:**

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /myApplication/test?sample=value HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 78
< Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 08:08:31 GMT
<
```

My custom CorsFilter works fine in my application.

What did I wrong? How to configure apache CorsFiler in my application instead of custom CorsFiler??

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also found similar problem with spring framework. I've solved this by adding **X-XSRF-TOKEN** in response header.

Try to add. It may solve the problem.

```
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Comment: The custom cors filter works fine..How to enable apache tomcat-catalina  Cors Filter in my application.

Comment: In that case you need to restrict by using Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
For example 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.myhost.com